# Why does Postgres optimizer switch to nested loop for join?

Tags: postgresql, performance, query-optimization, postgis

Using Postgres and Postgis I was experiencing a very slow spatial join using `st_equals`.  Out of curiosity, I tried using `=` instead, and the join was much faster.  Using `EXPLAIN`, I noticed that the `st_equals` join uses a nested loop, while the `=` uses a hash join.

I am far from an expert here - what is going on?  I have found the faster option here, but there could be times when I'd prefer to use `st_equals` AND have it be speedy...

For what it is worth, the `geom` columns from both tables are both gist indexed, and [st_equals takes advantage of indices](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/indexing.html).  Both tables have ~220K rows.

Here are the two select queries, followed by the two EXPLAIN results.  (Yes, I am finding records in one table that don't exist in the other, and yes I know there are other ways to do this but for now let's set that aside!)

A

```
explain
 select p1.geom from schema1.parcel p1
   join schema2.parcel p2
    on st_equals(p2.geom, p1.geom)
  where
    p2.pid is null
```

B

```
explain
 select p1.geom from schema1.parcel p1
   join schema2.parcel p2
     on p2.geom = p1.geom
  where
    p2.pid is null
```

A EXPLAIN

```
Gather  (cost=1000.42..2819605.27 rows=808 width=296)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.42..2818524.47 rows=337 width=296)
        Join Filter: st_equals(p2.geom, p1.geom)
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on parcel p1  (cost=0.00..9390.93 rows=95393 width=296)
        ->  Index Scan using parcel_pkey on parcel p2  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=300)
              Index Cond: (pid IS NULL)
```

B EXPLAIN

```
Gather  (cost=1004.45..10776.96 rows=229 width=296)
  Workers Planned: 2
  ->  Hash Join  (cost=4.45..9754.06 rows=95 width=296)
        Hash Cond: (p1.geom = p2.geom)
        ->  Parallel Seq Scan on parcel p1  (cost=0.00..9390.93 rows=95393 width=296)
        ->  Hash  (cost=4.44..4.44 rows=1 width=300)
              ->  Index Scan using parcel_pkey on parcel p2  (cost=0.42..4.44 rows=1 width=300)
                    Index Cond: (pid IS NULL)
```

(if this is better on the gis.stackexchange site, please let me know...)

Comment: Could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for your SQL statement? And the ddl for the tables and indexes involved? All in plain text as an update to your original question

Comment: "and st_equals takes advantage of indices."  That might be true in general, but obviously it is not true in your case.  Without seeing the table and index definitions, it is hard to speculate on why that might be.

Comment: A note on a common reason to join on `st_equals()`: if you need to establish whether different rows of different tables use the same original geometry, give each geometry a unique identifier at the origin and make sure to pass it along. Then, an `integer`-based `gid` would be quick and easy to compare - you can use a regular, index-backed `=` operator, and also the values you'll be comparing are shorter, lighter and easier to compare. For manipulated geometries, you can maintain a `jsonb` describing operations and their inputs and params, through all steps that resulted in a given geometry.

Comment: @Zegarek - I like your suggestion, though unfortunately I have an existing set of polygons and a "new" set of polygons and need to determine which "new" polygons I don't already have, and the only thing I have to go on is the geometry itself.  It has crossed my mind to somehow hash the geometries and comparing hash values instead, though I haven't yet experimented with doing so....would the expense of hashing be worth it.  I have to imagine that my use case is pretty common and that there should be a good, fast approach.  Perhaps I should post on gis.stackechange a new question...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's easy to explain: hash and merge join are only possible if the join condition uses the equality operator (`=`). Since your join condition is on a function result (`st_equals(p2.geom, p1.geom)`), PostgreSQL cannot use either of these join algorithms and has to resort to a nested loop join.  `st_equals()` is quite different from `=`, by the way.

The best you can do to speed such a query up id a GiST index on the join condition on the bigger of the tables, but that will still be slow if both tables are big. Also, if the geometries involved are complicated (many vertices), processing will probably be slower. Perhaps you can use `st_simplify()`.

Comment: That makes sense and is simple enough.  Is there any way to convince postgres to do a faster join with st_equals?  (yes, it is different from =, and I would prefer to use it if possible)

Comment: I see your update about speed.  I have a GiST index on both geometry fields, and still the st_equals join is so slow it is unusable.  I am thinking I must be overlooking something, as there aren't that many records involved - I would imagine that st_equals can be functionally usable in situations similar to this, no?

Answer (score 0):

In case of join postgres switches to nested join for below reasons:

1. One/Both of the column of joining table does not have index.
2. If nested join provides result quicker than hash/merge join.
3. Sometimes analysis provides wrong explain analysis if information is not updated.